# Rails - hide database credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, credentials

Say one is in need to create Ruby On Rails application using third party's database without the possibility to see/get the database credentials.

Above may seem pretty crazy, but I am in this exact situation right now. The application will run on my server (only I have physical/remote access), the database will be theirs (third party company) and I cannot have access to it.

Any way of encrypting the database.yml file is pointless since I can do the following:

```
config = Rails.configuration.database_configuration
username = config[Rails.env]["username"]
password = config[Rails.env]["password"]
```

I desperately need a way to achieve given goals, and I hope it is possible. Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can't have access to the database.... it's not clear what you expect. You can't access a database without credentials if it expects credentials.

Comment: It is pretty simple from my point of view: I am creating the application for the company A. The company A want me to maintain the application, service it, upgrade and fix if necessary. I will host the application on my servers. The company A needs me to ensure them that I will not have any kind of access to their data/database.

Comment: ... If they don't give you access you don't have access. I don't even understand the issue-do they think you have access now? How would you magically gain access because you wrote an application?

Comment: Of your app accesses their database, you have access to their database-that's what database access means. If your app doesn't work without their data then you need access. They can control what you have access to, what you can edit, etc. and if that isn't sufficient, provide something like RESTful access to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always run a rails console and do whatever you want on their database :/ I don't really see the point in this.

They can create a new user on the database and give you it's credentials and then limit what you can see and do on database level. You can read how to do it for PostgreSQL [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/user-manag.html).